# the result of dataGridView are some rows white c# windows forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

when i press the "button1" appear 2 rows, with blank rows.
My LIST have 2 elements.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    dataGridViewListaRES.Columns.Clear();
    dataGridViewListaRES.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridViewListaRES.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    resList.Sort((r1, r2) => r1.comparar.CompareTo(r2.comparar));
    dataGridViewListaRES.DataSource = resList;

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column1.Name = "user";
    column1.HeaderText = "user";
    column1.DataPropertyName = "user";
    dataGridViewListaRES.Columns.Add(column1);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column2.Name = "espetaculo";
    column2.HeaderText = "espetaculo";
    column2.DataPropertyName = "espetaculo";
    dataGridViewListaRES.Columns.Add(column2);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column3.Name = "data";
    column3.HeaderText = "data";
    column3.DataPropertyName = "data";
    dataGridViewListaRES.Columns.Add(column3);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column4 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column4.Name = "bilhetes";
    column4.HeaderText = "bilhetes";
    column4.DataPropertyName = "bilhetes";
    dataGridViewListaRES.Columns.Add(column4);

    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column5 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column5.Name = "horaInicio";
    column5.HeaderText = "horaInicio";
    column5.DataPropertyName = "horaInicio";
    dataGridViewListaRES.Columns.Add(column5);
}
```

Someone help??

Comment: and your question is...??

Comment: Your DataPropertyName of yours columns must be the same of your columns of datasource 'resList'

Comment: Yes, my columns in LIST have the same name in DataPropertyName

Comment: My question is, why rows appear in blank because had dates.